# Including Allegro 5 Issue

Tags: allegro5

I just installed Allegro 5 from the terminal as outlined here: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/OSX#Preliminaries. However, when I try to write a program, it has trouble including allegro.h. I have tried:

```
    #include <"allegro5/allegro5.h">
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main () {
        cout<<"foo"<<endl;
    }
```

but I get the following error when I compile (using g++):

```
foo.cpp:1:33: error: "allegro5/allegro5.h": No such file or directory
```

I have also tried:

```
    #include <"/usr/local/include/allegro5/allegro5.h">
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main () {
        cout<<"foo"<<endl;
    }
```

but I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
foo.cpp:1:52: error: "/usr/local/include/allegro5/allegro5.h": No such file or directory
```

I know the file at /usr/local/include/allegro5/allegro5.h exists. I have already tried #include <"/usr/local/include/allegro5/allegro.h"> and #include <"allegro5/allegro.h"> as well all with similar results. I know this is a pretty basic question and I just want to be able to write a program which can successfully include allegro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes are erroneous and the file is not correct. It should be:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```